# Spillage biot in Remix

Tags: remix

I had used https://tinyurl.com/bdeywjnc while creating remix slippage bot.

Here is my contract created https://etherscan.io/address/0x001a3f8d6f808968bdd7bd33d8490af44d668907

But it has transferred to some other address my ETH, and now I am not able to withdraw anything from my contract because of 0 ETH.

Anyway I can get my funds back?

Comment: You have been scammed. There's nothing you could do on-chain to recover the ether.